# Express hold a request until last request is finished

Tags: node.js, express

So I'm writing an application in node.js+express which I want to achieve the following goal.

1. User POST many requests at a nearly same time (like with command `curl...&` which `&` makes it run at the background)
2. Process each request at one time, hold other requests before one is finished. The order can be determined by request arrive time, if same then choose randomly. So if I POST 5 requests to add things in the database at nearly the same time, the first request will be added into database first, while other requests will be held (not responding anything yet) until the first request is been processed and respond with a `200` code then follow on processing the second request.

Is it possible to achieve this with express, so when I send couple requests at one time, it won't occur issue like something isn't add into MongoDB properly.

Comment: Web requests like POST always runs independently of each other i.e. you cannot stop other requests from same user while you process one.

Comment: If you are worried about database updates, don't because database updates are sequential and atomic in nature i.e. if req call the database in sequence, then database will update the data in sequence. If you are worried about same user making many requests, then simply don't allow users to make calls so fast by changing your frontend.

Comment: @Rash I mean like if server detects a request has enter before it, it’ll hold the request by not responding them until the request that enters before them finishes

Comment: @Rash I’m currently running into the issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55661888/8460574), not sure why but the issue exists.

Comment: I don't think you want to handle one request at a time. You want to handle one request PER USER at a time which I said is not possible without custom code. The best way is to stop the user from making multiple calls is in the UI.

Comment: @Rash what do you mean “per user”? In the issue I’m entering, the API is for adding cars to db where it doesn’t matter who adds it.

Comment: ah, got it. I just assumed you wanted it per user. In that case you already have the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up middleware before/after your routes to queue up and dequeue requests if one is in progress. As people have mentioned this is not really best practice, but this is a way to do it within a single process (will not work for serverless models)

```
const queue = [];
const inprogress = null;

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (inprogress) {
    queue.push({req, res, next})
  } else {
    inprogress = res;
  }
})

app.get('/your-route', (req, res, next) => {
  // run your code
  res.json({ some: 'payload' })
  next();
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  inprogress = null;
  if (queue.length > 0) {
    const queued = queue.shift();
    inprogress = queued.res;
    queued.next();
  }
  next();
})
```